# Remove/Redirect /page/ from homepage Wordpress

Tags: homepage

hello i want to ask how to remove ex : /page/2/ /page/4/ from my homepage? and yes my homepage is using page builder, so https://surgatekno.com/page/2/ still can be accessable and showing the same content of my homepage https://surgatekno.com/.

the question is same how to disable like make it page not found or redirect it back to / instead of /page/2/ or /page/3/ and so on. (because its showing the same content and maybe bad for SEO)

Answer (score 0):

This is usually due to the homepage being set to list your posts. This is the default configuration for all WordPress sites since WordPress is a blogging platform first and a CMS through proper configuration.

You can fix this by setting a static homepage rather than showing all your posts. Take a look in the [reading settings](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Reading_Screen) to change your front page to be static and your posts page to live somewhere else.

From [the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Reading_Screen):

> Use this setting to determine if your posts or a "static" Page
>   displays as your blog's front (main) page. This setting displays only
>   if you have one or more Pages defined. Please note: static front page
>   plugins and other 'posts display' control/restriction plugins may
>   affect how these features work!